# How to get the clicked element from the array? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

I would like to ask how can I access to the clicked element's id from the array?
I want to make a memory game, so If I click on the card I want to know what is the id of that clicked card.

```js
const cards = [
    { id: 1, name: "austria", imgSrc: "/img/austria.png"},
    { id: 2, name: "belgium", imgSrc: "/img/belgium.png"},
    /* ... */
]

const cardsPair = [...cards]
const wholeCardsList = [...cardsPair, ...cards]
const shuffledCards = wholeCardsList.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

let actualcard = null

function initBoard() {
    const board_container = document.querySelector('.board_container');
    let displayCards = shuffledCards.map((item) => {
        return `
        <div class="card_container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="face-side">
                    <img src="/img/question.png" alt="Question mark">
                </div>
                <div class="back-side">
                    <img src=${item.imgSrc} alt="${item.name} flag icon">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;      
    }).join("");

    board_container.innerHTML = displayCards;

    const card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
    card.forEach((e) => {
        e.addEventListener("click", () => {
            e.parentElement.classList.toggle("flipped");
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of the card object in the array will be the same as the index of the clicked `card_container` inside its parent, so you can do

```
e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const child = e.closest('.card-container');
  const index = [...child.parentElement.children].indexOf(child);
```

And then look up the index in the array of objects.

Or you can put the ID as a data attribute when creating the HTML. Change

```
    return `
    <div class="card_container">
```

to

```
    return `
    <div class="card_container" data-id="${item.id}">
```

and then you'll be able to retrieve it with

```
e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const { id } = e.currentTarget.dataset;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I dont get some part of your answer :D

Comment: What don't you get?

Comment: hm, I worget to update :D so this part: `e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const { id } = e.currentTarget.dataset;`
  - const { id } ?

Comment: That takes the `id` property value from the `datalist` object and puts it into a variable named `id`.

Comment: Why is it in square braces?

Comment: It's not, it's within curly braces. Why is it within curly braces? Because that's how the syntax works, it's just how things are.

Comment: Thank you, sorry, but I haven't seen this `const { id } = something;` syntax before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247603/discussion-between-surge-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 1):

Just set an `id` attribute to the `card` element, and on `click` event get the `event.currentTarget.id`

```
const cards = [
    { id: 1, name: "austria", imgSrc: "/img/austria.png"},
    { id: 2, name: "belgium", imgSrc: "/img/belgium.png"}
    ...
]

const cardsPair = [...cards]
const wholeCardsList = [...cardsPair, ...cards]
const shuffledCards = wholeCardsList.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

let actualcard = null

function initBoard() {
    const board_container = document.querySelector('.board_container');
    let displayCards = shuffledCards.map((item) => {
        return `
        <div class="card_container">
            <div class="card" id="${item.id}">
                <div class="face-side">
                    <img src="/img/question.png" alt="Question mark">
                </div>
                <div class="back-side">
                    <img src=${item.imgSrc} alt="${item.name} flag icon">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;      
    }).join("");

    board_container.innerHTML = displayCards;

    const card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
    card.forEach((c) => {
        e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            console.log(e.currentTarget.id)
            c.parentElement.classList.toggle("flipped");
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution throws an error: e is not defined

Comment: You are welcome, but It should be defined, as it's a `click` event parameter, make sure you add it.

Comment: yes, I added it to the click event as a parameter